# How to easily found the places that I changed using diff in intellij

Tags: intellij-idea

I have a very long file under git repository, and then I made some changes on it. And I use the diff tool in intellij to check the changes that I made, but it is not as easy as eclipse. On the right side, there's lots of highlights points that make me hard to figure where I changed. I have to go through the whole file to check. Is there any easy way like in eclipse ?

Answer (score 0):

Intelij has a local history. Right click on your file to see it. It shows recent changes of the file.
Have you tried it?